# How to host number of websites under similer url

Tags: python, django, url, dns, pythonanywhere

I have a site build in `site123` (`site123` is a WYSIWYG and it dose not support code export). I use it as a nice designed landing page and product's catalog. so I have:
`https://app.site123.com/?w=my_site` this site has no back-end (not supported by `site123`). and I have another site build in `django` for payments and other stuff like this I host it on `pythonanywhere`, So I also have `http://my_website_with_backed.pythonanywhere.com/`.
Now, I buy a domain from `GoDaddy` and I would like to know if there is a way to connect the 2 websites under the same url??. like:
`site123 website`: `www.catalog.my_own_url.com`
`django website`: `www.payment.my_own_url.com`
Thank you

Comment: web server like `Apache` or `NGINX` has `"virtual host"` to run many domains (even diffferent - ie. `www.a.com`, `www.b.com`) on the same IP. But it needs to have server to keep apache and pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can do a redirect from the subdomains to your page but in this case you will have the 3rd party URL displayed and not your subdomain.
2. You can probably use a simple HTML structure with iFrames to include your page. Like connecting your subdomains with a server and hosting there a HTML page which loads your python or WYSIWYG page.
3. If site123 is a static landing page without many changes or dynamic elements, I would think about **scraping** it with a script and transfer it to a server which also supports python (e.g. Amazon AWS). In this case you can get rid of pythonanymwhere and use your subdomains.
   Then you can either use site123 (and scrape it every night for example) or use another WYSIWYG editor to build a page and deploy it to your server.